# Have a problem importing to MapPoint through a C# DLL

Tags: c#, interop, import, mappoint

We're trying to import a file from a C# dll into MapPoint, and can get it to read the data just fine, but we are having trouble with MapPoint not recognizing all of the addresses.  Currently, our file contains not only address information, but latitude and longitude as well (under the headers of Lat and Lon).  Is there any options we can set, or any methods we can use that will allow us to tell MapPoint to use the latitude and Longitude in place of, or in addition to the address?  So far I've not found any, but I could be looking in the wrong place anyway.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to locate Location objects by Latitude, Longitude coordinates, and to locate input data (eg. from Excel or Access) using Longitude,Latitude coordinates. How are you actually creating the data in MapPoint?

Richard

Comment: Data gets imported from an excel spreadsheet into mappoint.  It has Latitude and Longitude columns.

Comment: Yes when you use the Data Import Wizard it has to be one or the other. For Excel spreadsheets, you could import the data as two datasets?  Alternative you could write an addin or utility which 'manually' imported the data points. This could easily choose the location method as appropriate but would not be able to input data fields (just name, text, pushpin symbol). Another option would be to geocode the address data so all of your Excel data rows have coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Map Point 2010 will allow you to enter a Location based on Longitude and Latitude. Are you using the Web Based Bing API or the Map Point application API?  I am using this same functionality in one of my applications.   If you are using the application API, the ShowFindDialog method will even throw up a pre-rolled window with search criteria for a location, and you can enter latitude and longitude there.  See the MSDN article if you have detailed questions.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa562422.aspx